# Is it possible to send a stream of Buffers with an HTML response on Node-RED?

Tags: node-red

I have created the following flow on Node-RED:

[image]

```json
[{"id":"6f429f2902eff7e3","type":"http in","z":"0a916e7281ac9a83","name":"","url":"/page","method":"get","upload":false,"swaggerDoc":"","x":180,"y":360,"wires":[["18ce8fb90a81c88d"]]},{"id":"2d2251b59a8f647b","type":"http response","z":"0a916e7281ac9a83","name":"","statusCode":"","headers":{"content-type":"text/html"},"x":670,"y":360,"wires":[]},{"id":"18ce8fb90a81c88d","type":"file in","z":"0a916e7281ac9a83","name":"","filename":"/home/user/page.html","format":"stream","chunk":false,"sendError":false,"encoding":"none","allProps":true,"x":420,"y":360,"wires":[["2d2251b59a8f647b"]]}]
```

Let's say that `page.html` is a huge HTML file (over 100MB)... I'd like to make this flow work in a way that I don't have to put this data on my flow at once, so I tried to make it work on a stream of buffers as the following:

[image]

I've also set the `Content-type` to `text/html` on the response node. But if I try to load this page on `http://localhost:1880/page`... My page doesn't load as expected. Is it possible to do? To send an entire webpage to the client as a stream of buffers just so I don't spend too much RAM memory on my server?

Answer (score 1):

No, the http-in/http-response nodes do not support HTTP Chunked encoding (which is what would be needed to make this work).

If you would like to implement such a feature, bring it up on the Discourse forum or in Slack to discuss it before raising a PR against the project on GitHub.

I won't comment on how a 100mb HTML file is a bad idea in general.

Comment: What's a PR? In this case, serving it as a static page configuring my `settings.js` file with the `httpStatic` parameter would also solve the issue... Wouldn't it?

Comment: A PR is a Pull Request (where you do the work to make the changes to the code and the project reviews them before accepting/declining them). Serving the file via the `httpStatic` may work, I'd have to test to see if it actually streams the file or loads it all into memory first.

Comment: As I can see the value in this (and it isn't the first time this question has been asked) I have added an item to the Node-RED backlog to support streamed responses. https://trello.com/c/C8795KWm/253-http-response-support-sending-a-message-sequence-as-a-chunked-response

Comment: I see... I've made some tests here. While using the httpStatic option the server memory stays the same even if I save GB files inside its folder... Also, while I'm loading the page from a client, the server memory stays the same while the client is loading it (I know, it's not a good idea to have a 100MB HTML file). So, it seems to work fine using the `httpStatic` in the cases that I've tested...